# Differentiation in Mathematica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, differentiation

I want to differentiate `f(x)=sin(x^2-1)` in Mathematica Software

I used this command

```
D[Sin[x^2 - 1], x]
```

The output is

```
2 x Cos[1 - x^2]
```

Why the angle is `1-x^2` instead of `x^2-1` ??

Thanks.

Comment: I believe this question should be asked in http://math.stackexchange.com/ it seems off-topic here in stackoverflow.

Comment: Related to http://math.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the cosine function is [even](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Even_and_odd_functions), the two forms are equivalent (`cos(x^2 - 1) = cos(1 - x^2)`).

Apparently the simplification algorithms Mathematica uses were a tad over-enthusiastic in this case.